# Function that alternately combines two given arrays into a single array

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to write a function in C that takes two arrays of characters, alternately combines the elements of the arrays into one new array and then returns a pointer to the new array.

My program below compiles fine but produces an incorrect, different output every time the program is run.

If anyone could help point out where I'm going wrong I'd be very grateful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char* altCombine(char[], char[], int, int);

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char arr1[4] = {'e','f','g', 'h'};
    char arr2[4] = {'a','b','c','d'};
    int size1 = 4;
    int size2 = 4;
    char* altArr;
    altArr = altCombine(arr1, arr2, size1, size2);
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        printf("%c \n", altArr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

char* altCombine(char arr1[], char arr2[], int size1, int size2){
    int i = 0, a = 0, b = 0;
    int totalSize = (size1 + size2);
    char* nArr = malloc(sizeof(char) * totalSize);
    char newArr[totalSize];
    while(i < totalSize){
        if(a < size1){
            newArr[i] = arr1[a];
            i++; 
            a++;    
        }
        if(b < size2){
            newArr[i] = arr2[b];
            i++;
            b++;
        } 
    }    
    nArr = &newArr[0];
    return nArr;    
}
```

Comment: `nArr = &newArr[0]; return nArr;` --> `return memcpy(nArr, newArr, totalSize);`

Comment: `nArr = &newArr[0];` `newArr` is local to `altCombine` and goes *out_of_scope* (and the memory is release for reuse) on `return`. So your `nArr` pointer points to memory that no longer exists on return to `main`. `memcpy (nArr, newArr, totalsize);` instead of `nArr = &newArr[0];` --- what @BLUEPIXY said...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this

```
  char* nArr = malloc(sizeof(char) * totalSize);
```

you are on the right track. You allocate the space you need on the heap, so the memory stays valid until explicitly freed.

This

```
  char newArr[totalSize];
```

on the other hand allocates `newArr` on the function's stack, so it is gone the moment the function returns.

Further more as you have `nArr` you just do not need `newArr`.

So to finalise the approach you to took replace all `newArr` by `nArr` and drop this line

```
  nArr = &newArr[0];
```

and you are done.

---

As mentioned in some comments already you alternatively could copy `newArr`'s content to where `nArr` points by using

```
  memcpy(nArr, newArr, sizeof newArr);
```

instead of

```
  nArr = &newArr[0];
```

The latter statement does not copy the array's content, but just assigns to the *pointer* `nArr` the  address of `newArr`'s 1st element. This does not help you as the values under this address will be freed when the function returns (see above).

Also overwriting the value of `nArr` leaks the memory allocated by the previous call to `malloc()`.

---

Unrelated to your issue: All those `int`s should better be `size_t`s.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer! I've been scratching my head all day. You've made my night!

Answer (score 0):

You have already allocated memory so you can use same char array to store result and then return it
This might help you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char* altCombine(char[], char[], int, int);

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char arr1[4] = {'e','f','g', 'h'};
    char arr2[4] = {'a','b','c','d'};
    int size1 = 4;
    int size2 = 4;
    char* altArr;
    altArr = altCombine(arr1, arr2, size1, size2);
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        printf("%c \n", *(altArr+i));
    }

    return 0;
}

char* altCombine(char* arr1, char* arr2, int size1, int size2){
    int i = 0, a = 0, b = 0;
    int totalSize = (size1 + size2);
    char* nArr =(char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * totalSize);

    while(i < totalSize){
        if(a < size1){
            nArr[i] = arr1[a];//nArr used instead of newArr 
            i++; 
            a++;    
        }
        if(b < size2){
            nArr[i] = arr2[b];//nArr used instead of newArr
            i++;
            b++;
        } 
    }    

    return nArr; //char pointer returned   
}
```